# ReactJS Array Parse inside Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a object

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "collectionName": "dsa",
    "collectionItemsID": [
        "ad",
        "deneme1"
    ],
    "ownerOfCollection": "117961395738439786389",
    "createdAt": "2022-06-16T12:54:52.146Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-06-16T12:54:52.146Z"
}
```

When I push to front like that in **ReactJS**

{collection.collectionItemsID}

I am getting output with joined.

**addeneme1**

It needs to be seperated. I didnt wanted to use javascript for seperate. I need to learn how to do correctly. I think I needs to use Object.keys but I am failed with this way.

**How can I map collectionItemsID in ReactJS?**

this is the example way of I wanted to implement object outputs

```
          {data.map((item, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>
                <input
                  id={item.user_id}
                  type="checkbox"
                  value={item.user_id}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  checked={isChecked}
                />
              </td>
              <td>{item.user_id}</td>
              <td>{item.user_name}</td>
              <td className="isbanned">{item.isbanned}</td>
              <td>{item.registration_date}</td>
              <td>{item.last_login}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
```

---

**Solution**

```
<div>

            {Object.keys(collection).length > 0 ? <div>
                <h1>{collection.name}</h1>
                <p>{collection.description}</p>
                {collection.collectionItemsID.map(function (itemID) {
                    return <a href={`/${itemID}`}>{itemID}</a>
                })}
            </div> : <p>Loading...</p>}
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of what your issue is?

Comment: My Issue is its an object and collectionItemsID has items in. I need to reach collectionItemsID by one by. 

{collection.collectionItemsID}

this is the way of directly reach to every item. but I want to reach one by one

this renders as

{collection.collectionItemsID}

>>>> addeneme1.

So basically how can I map collectionItemsID

Comment: `collectionItemsID` is an array, so what do you _concretely_ want to have happen here? Two `<a>` elements, one for each string in `collectionItemsID`? A single `<a>` with the content of collectionItemsID joined with `/`? There seem to be details missing here that prevent answering this question.

Comment: Looks like href part made more complicated. I just removed. I want to map collectionItemsID inside in object. when I mapped it I will be able to push to front each item has own links

Comment: Those words don't mean anything on their own, as arrays _are_ objects in JS. So: please show what exact output you want to achieve. You've shown the input you're working with, now edit your post to show what output that should become, and then show the code you already wrote to try to achieve that (and talk about how that went wrong and what you already tried/looked up/searched to understand why, and how to fix that).

Comment: <a href="/"+collectionItemsID>ad</a> (collectionItemsID will be ad for first output) -------
<a href="/"+collectionItemsID>deneme1</a>  (collectionItemsID will be deneme1 for second output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

If you want have each entry in `collectionItemsID` to have it's own link, you need to use the `map` method of an array

```
collection.collectionItemsID.map(function(itemID) {
                    return <a href={`/${itemID}`}>{itemID}</a>
                })
```

### Explanation

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of `map` method

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

### Suggestions

1. You should always name your list attributes in plural form so instead of `collectionItemsID` it should be `collectionItemIDs` which indicates to anyone reading that it potentially have multiple values.
2. You should also not add the word `collection` to the attribute as the object itself is a collection. for example it should be

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "dsa",
    "itemIds": [
        "ad",
        "deneme1"
    ],
    "owner": "117961395738439786389",
    "createdAt": "2022-06-16T12:54:52.146Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-06-16T12:54:52.146Z"
}
```

This way when you have a variable holding the object, the code becomes

```
var collection = {....}
collection.name // dsa
collection.owner // 117961395738439786389
collection.itemIds // ["ad","deneme1"]
```

Comment: but the problem is its not array. its object and map function not working
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: I edited a little bit the code and I found the answer thanks for help

Comment: Thats great, could you also share here what your edit was that lead to your resolution, it might help the next person reading this post.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer of my question

```
        <div>

            {Object.keys(collection).length > 0 ? <div>
                <h1>{collection.name}</h1>
                <p>{collection.description}</p>
                {collection.collectionItemsID.map(function (itemID) {
                    return <a href={`/${itemID}`}>{itemID}</a>
                })}
            </div> : <p>Loading...</p>}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is...

```
<a href={`/${collectionItemsID.join(' ')}`}>
```

Comment: not like that. I wanted to handle render part.

{collection.collectionItemsID}

>>> addeneme1

but I need to map object inside  collectionItemsID

Comment: @Samet I guess I'm a bit confused on what you want. Can you give a more detail example in your original question? Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).